# Chatting Application SMS bubble ( android )

Tags: java, android, listview, sms, chat

I am working on android chat application. I need to use bubbles for chat sms. Is there any working example for this. It will be of great use if someone who have worked on such applications can guide me with few working examples.

I already send and receive sms but I couldn't show it in bubble and listview, can anyone guide me in clear steps : How can I do it and how much activity I need  and how can I do that ?

Comment: Check out this project https://github.com/madhur/android-chat-starter

Comment: @MadhurAhuja Your library is excellent. But is there any way to import it through Gradle? Am able to run it in Android studio, but is there any tutorial on how to integrate it?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not created a library for this. You need to copy the required layouts and 9 patch images if you want to integrate it...

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://thetechnib.blogspot.com/2010/12/android-tutorial-custom-adapter-for.html) is a tutorial to make one **note:** The images used in the bubble is in the 9 patch format you should read about it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html)